# How to Give input image to trained model ? expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, data-science

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model=tf.keras.models.load_model('model_ex-024_acc-0.996875.h5')
img_array = cv2.imread('30.jpg')  # convert to array

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_rgb = cv2.resize(img_rgb,(224,224),3)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)  # graph it
plt.show()
model.predict(img_rgb)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expand your input image dimension as the model expects. And you can do that using `np.expand_dims`. Additionally you may want to scale your image.

```
img_rgb = cv2.resize(img_rgb,(224,224),3)  # resize
img_rgb = np.array(img_rgb).astype(np.float32)/255.0  # scaling
img_rgb = np.expand_dims(img_rgb, axis=0)  # expand dimension
y_pred = model.predict(img_rgb) # prediction
y_pred_class = y_pred.argmax(axis=1)[0]
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: how I can print out the class of prediction results?

Comment: yes, why not. assign the predicted value to a variable like `y_pred = model.predict(img_rgb)` and if it's a classification problem then you should apply `argmax` on `y_pred` to get the class index having highest probability.