# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, None, None)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, data-generation

I'm new at Tensorflow and I try to classify PDF files with a CNN by converting it to images and feeding it to a model.
I created a custom DataGenerator with keras (using [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-custom-data-generators-in-keras-de56f013581c)) and I get a ValueError when running model.fit().

My input layer when i run model.summary() is : **input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]**

Below is my code for the __ getitem __ and __data_generation :

```
    def __getitem__(self, index):
    index = self.index[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    batch = [self.indices[k] for k in index]
    X, y = self.__data_generation(batch)
    return X, y

    def __data_generation(self, batch):
        df = self.df
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)
        for i, id in enumerate(batch):
            
            # Loading the image :
            doc_row = df.loc[i]
            path = str(doc_row['PATH'])
            path = os.path.join(dataset_path,path)
            typologie = str(doc_row['TYPOLOGIE'])
            img_i = convert_from_path(path)[0]

            # Converting the image :
            img_i = img_i.resize((224,224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            gray_img_i = ImageOps.grayscale(img_i)
            array_image_i = np.array(gray_img_i,dtype='float32')
            array_image_i = np.expand_dims(array_image_i, axis=0)
            X[i,] = array_image_i
            y[i] = self.map_classes[typologie]
        X = [np.array(X)]
        Y = np.array(y)
        Y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y, num_classes = self.num_classes)
        return X, Y
```

**ValueError**: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, None, None)

I tried to use the np.expand_dims() as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552663/how-to-give-input-image-to-trained-model-expected-input-1-to-have-4-dimensions), but it doesn't solve my problem.

I suspect the conversion part to be bad, but I have no clue of where could the problem come from.

Comment: Could you maybe provide the output of "np.shape(np.array(X))" if you print it before the line "X = [np.array(X)]"?

Comment: @MarcFelix the shape is (1, 224, 224). I just found the error by looking it up, thank you ! I needed to delete the grayscaling to get the right shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 errors in this code:

1. I replaced

   ```
   gray_img_i = ImageOps.grayscale(img_i)
   array_image_i = np.array(gray_img_i,dtype='float32')
   ```

   By :

   ```
   array_image_i = np.array(img_i,dtype='float32')
   ```

By doing this I changed the shape of each image from (1, 224, 224) to (1, 224, 224, 3).
The "3" in the shape means I need a RGB image (3 channels per image), so removing the grayscaling is quite useful !

2. I replaced

   ```
   doc_row = df.loc[i]
   ```

   By :

   ```
   doc_row = df.loc[id]
   ```

I had inverted **i** and **id** in my *for* loop.